# Is it possible to use ASP.NET validation controls when I need to modify HTML when validation fails?

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

Let's say that I have the following HTML for a text box on an ASP.NET page:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

It is easy enough to add a required field validator to this page like this.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valMyTextBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMyTextBox" ErrorMessage="My Text Box is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But I need to modify the HTML slightly if this text box fails validation.  I need to add a CSS class to the DIV.  So if the user leaves this field blank I need the HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="myClass error">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Is this possible?  I can't figure out if there is a way to write code behind that only fires if this particular validator control fails validation or something.  I know I can write code that runs when the entire page is not valid.  But I just want this code to run when this validator returns invalid.  Hope this makes sense.

Corey

Comment: this could be solved by javascript or any other scripting languages are you familiar with them?

Comment: Yes, of course there are lots of different ways to solve this.  Specifically I am trying to figure out if there is a way to solve this using ASP.NET validation controls.

Comment: checkout this answer it might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806045/696978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer in a different StackOverflow question.  You can see it here:  [How do I add an additional CSS class on a surrounding DIV for failed form validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869662/how-do-i-add-an-additional-css-class-on-a-surrounding-div-for-failed-form-validat).

Comment: This requires a postback. An alternative is to create a custom validator, to which you can specify both a client-side javascript function which can do the client validation, and you can provide a backend function that will run when post-back occurs

Answer (score 0):

OK I think this might help even though I am not to sure on the exact ways to do this

```
<div class=<%Response.Write(validateTextBox())%>>
```

that function which would be on the server that you would call to change the name of the class depending on the text box

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it without Postback is to override the default asp.net validation scripts.  I posted an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857696/618044